# 404 after open system config sections

Tags: magento-1.9

My system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <cart_shipping_mthd>
            <label>Shipping method</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </cart_shipping_mthd>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <cart_shipping_mthds>
            <label>Configuration</label>
            <tab>cart_shipping_mthd</tab>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <configuration>
                    <label>Insurance Upsell Configuration</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled>
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </enabled>
                        <discount_rate>
                            <label>Discount rate (in %) </label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </discount_rate>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text>
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox popup text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_text translate="label">
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_text>
                    </fields>
                </configuration>
            </groups>
        </cart_shipping_mthds>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And my ACL:

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <cart_shipping_mthds translate="title" module="cms">
                                        <title>Cart insurance upsells</title>
                                    </cart_shipping_mthds>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

When I open cart_shipping_mthds i show 404. Where is my fault

Comment: please clear cache and session

Comment: @jigsparmar done

Comment: Its open or still error ??

Comment: @jigsparmar still error

Comment: you add acl code in which file?>>

Comment: @jigsparmar sorry. My fault was session /-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create file adminhtml.xml

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <cart_shipping_mthds translate="title">
                                        <title>Cart insurance upsells</title>
                                    </cart_shipping_mthds>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

clear cache and session 
and open admin in private window